# When didReceiveMemoryWarning and applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning is called?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If both methods are implemented didReceiveMemoryWarning and applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning which one will be called first, if the memory is low.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that they belong to different interfaces. One is for the application delegate, the other for uiviewcontroller. They should both try to release as much unneeded memory as possible.

I don't think the order is guaranteed anywhere, but it will probably be consistent. Set breakpoints or add log statements to measure which is called first.